# EntityManagerFactory is closed when page is reloaded

Tags: java, hibernate

I use this Java code to make SQL queries using Hibernate in JSF application and SQLite database:

**Hibernate configuration file:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/sqliteDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.SystemUsers"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Factory**:

```
 public class HibernateUtil
    {
        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        static
        {
            try
            {
                StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry
                    = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
                Metadata metaData
                    = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

**I use this code to call Hibernate factory class:**

```
private List<SystemUserObj> generateSystemUsers()
    {
        try (SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory())
        {
            Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

            List<SystemUsers> dataList = session.createQuery("from SystemUsers").list();

            for (SystemUsers user : dataList)
            {
                ........
            }

            session.flush();
            tr.commit();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Then I open the web page first time data is loaded properly but when I open the page page second time I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?
Probably my factory class is not properly implemented?

Also how I can refactor the Factory code so I can made several requests simultaneously?

Comment: Use more modern tutorials... Hibernate utils with retrieving sessionfactories is very, very old school

Comment: @Kukeltje Some more specific information?

Comment: No, sorry, I only do 'jsf' support and use JPA.